# How do I create 6 parallel texts aligned by paragraph, with 3 texts on each page?

Tags: vertical-alignment, parallel

I want to typeset a hexaglot work. Each language will occupy its own column, and there will be 3 columns on each page. The text will be aligned by paragraphs and headings.

Basically, I want something that looks like this:

```
              Left Page                                Right Page
+--------------------------------------+ +--------------------------------------+
| Heading    | Тема 1     | Primero    | | Χαίρετε!   | 標題1       |    ספרות  |
| -------    | ---------  | ---------- | | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| English t- | Це не рос- | No tengo   | | Πώς είσαι; | 其實我不知  |  פוליטיקה |
| ext taking | ійський т- | nada. Pero | | Καλό.      | 中國。      | לערך אינו |
| up 3 lines | екст а ук- | Juan tiene | |            | 我使用的是  | ציו ישראל |
|            | раїнській. |            | |            | 翻譯。      |    תבניות |
|            |            |            | |            |            |            |
| Heading 2  | Дуже довг- | Segundo    | | Ελληνική ε | 我喜歡牛肉！| בהיסטוריה |
| ---------- | ий Тема    | ---------- | | ίναι ωραία | ---------- | ---------- |
|            | ---------- |            | | ---------- |            |            |
| Text taki- | Круто!     | Estoy abu- | | Σ 'αγαπώ.  | 你喜歡牛肉  |   אם מפתח |
| ng up 2    |            | rrido.     | |            | 嗎？       |   קישורים |
|            |            |            | |            |            |    תקשורת |
+--------------------------------------+ +--------------------------------------+
```

I looked at the parallel library but I couldn't figure out how to put in 3 columns. I also looked at parcolumns but I couldn't get text the two pages to line up.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: I've seen this before.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53544/divide-the-page-into-2-parts The trick is to use the parallel usepackage.

Comment: I strongly suggest looking at [tag:ConTeXt].

Comment: @MartinSchröder: [not in this case](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128574/14066).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

REVISED VERSION (AUTOMATED PAGEBREAK CONTROL):

As with the manual solution, one initializes a "special table" with `\newspecialtable`.  Likewise, one enters any number of rows to the table with repeated invocations of the macro `\sixby{}{}{}{}{}{}`, once per row.  In this case, however, if a row would be so large as to push to the next page, the double-page is broken at that point and the complete new row is bumped to the next double-page.

When all the rows are entered via `\sixby`, one employs `\finishspecialtable`, to clear out the straggler rows onto a final double-page.  As a bonus, I added Russian and greek support to this MWE.  *I hope I am not inadvertantly cursing or using foreign foul language, as I just copied the foreign text from other pages on the site.*

**In case one doesn't spot it immediately, the table column width and overall maximum text height have been reset here (for demonstration purposes) to `\def\colwidth{1in}` and `\textheight=4in\relax`, respectively.  They should be reset to appropriate values for actual use.**

The `\printtabtoks` method came from Herbert at [How to programmatically make tabular rows using `\whiledo` ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/how-to-programmatically-make-tabular-rows-using-whiledo)

EDITED to handle centering and quotes.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tabindex}
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{%
  \@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks\stepcounter{tabindex}#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\synctabindex[1]{\setcounter{tabindex}{\value{#1}}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\def\colwidth{1in}
\newcounter{sptstartrow}
\newcounter{sptendrow}
\newcounter{entries}
\newcounter{pagerows}
\newlength\CurrentTableHeight
\newlength\CurrentRowHeight
\newsavebox\pagerow

\newcommand\newspecialtable{%
  \setcounter{sptendrow}{0}%
  \setcounter{entries}{0}%
  \setcounter{pagerows}{0}%
  \setlength\CurrentTableHeight{0pt}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\sixby[6]{%
  \stepcounter{entries}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xa\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xb\endcsname{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#2}}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xc\endcsname{#3}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xd\endcsname{\textgreek{#4}}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xe\endcsname{#5}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xf\endcsname{#6}%
  \synctabindex{entries}%
  \sbox{\pagerow}{\formatcol{a}\formatcol{b}\formatcol{c}\formatcol{d}\formatcol{e}\formatcol{f}}%
  \setlength\CurrentRowHeight{\ht\pagerow+\dp\pagerow}%
  \addtolength\CurrentTableHeight{\CurrentRowHeight}%
  \ifdim\CurrentTableHeight>\textheight %
    \makespecialtable[\thepagerows]%
    \setcounter{pagerows}{0}%
    \setlength\CurrentTableHeight{\CurrentRowHeight}%
    \else\fi%
  \stepcounter{pagerows}%
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\makespecialtable[1][\theentries]{%
  \setcounter{sptstartrow}{\thesptendrow}%
  \addtocounter{sptendrow}{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\thesptendrow > \theentries}{\setcounter{sptendrow}{\theentries}}{}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xa\endcsname &
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xb\endcsname &
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xc\endcsname & 
      \vphantom{\formatcol{d}\formatcol{e}\formatcol{f}}
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|p{\colwidth}|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xd\endcsname &
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xe\endcsname &
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xf\endcsname &
      \vphantom{\formatcol{a}\formatcol{b}\formatcol{c}}
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|p{\colwidth}|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand\formatcol[1]{%
   \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}X#1\endcsname\strut}%
}

\newcommand\finishspecialtable{\makespecialtable}

\textheight=4in\relax
\begin{document}
\centering
\newspecialtable
\sixby
  {Row 1: Title of {\centering \bfseries CENTERED\par} column 1 maybe a bit longer than column 3}%
  {Текст на русском языке}%
  {No tengo  nada. Pero Juan\begin{quote}\bfseries QUOTE\end{quote} tiene}%
  {Πώς είσαι Καλό.}%
  {while this is a test of a particularly extended line spanning a
    number of rows, more than all the others.  And I really mean more than all the others}%
  {T}
\sixby
  {Row 2: this is a test of a particularly extended line spanning a
    number of rows, more than all the others}%
  {Це не російський текст а українській.}%
  {Segundo}%
  {φύσις}%
  {Here is some text for this entry}%
  {column 6 entry maybe a bit longer than column 5}
\sixby
  {Row 3: this is a test of a longer line}%
  {Дуже довгий Тема}%
  {Estoy aburrido.}%
  {Και άλλο ελληνικό κείμενο}%
  {}%
  {column 6 entry maybe a bit longer than column 5}
\sixby
  {Row 4: this is a test of an extended rows}%
  {Круто!}%
  {Estoy aburrido.}%
  {ἀλλ' οὐ λέγουσι τὸ διὰ τί περὶ οὐδενός, οἷον διὰ}%
  {final text}%
  {column 6 entry maybe a bit longer than column 5}%
\sixby
  {Row 5: Title of column 1 maybe a bit longer than column 3}%
  {Текст на русском языке}%
  {No tengo  nada. Pero Juan tiene}%
  {Πώς είσαι Καλό.}%
  {while this is a test of a particularly extended line spanning a
    number of rows, more than all the others.  And I really mean more than all the others}%
  {T}
\sixby
  {Row 6: this is a test of a longer line}%
  {Це не російський текст а українській.}%
  {Segundo}%
  {φύσις}%
  {Here is some text for this entry}%
  {column 6 entry maybe a bit longer than column 5}
\sixby
  {Row 7: this is a test of an extended rows}%
  {Круто!}%
  {Estoy aburrido.}%
  {ἀλλ' οὐ λέγουσι τὸ διὰ τί περὶ οὐδενός, οἷον διὰ}%
  {final text}%
  {column 6 entry maybe a bit longer than column 5}%
\sixby
  {Row 8: Title of column 1 maybe a bit longer than column 3}%
  {Текст на русском языке}%
  {No tengo  nada. Pero Juan tiene}%
  {Πώς είσαι Καλό.}%
  {while this is a test of a particularly extended line spanning a
    number of rows, more than all the others.  And I really mean more than all the others}%
  {T}
\finishspecialtable
\end{document}
```

Here are shown the first two pages of output.  The MWE puts out 6 pages of output, demonstrating the auto-pagebreaks

[image]

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION (MANUAL PAGEBREAK CONTROL):

One initializes a "special table" with `\newspecialtable`.  Then, one enters any number of rows to the table with repeated invocations of the macro `\sixby{}{}{}{}{}{}`, once per row.  When all the rows are entered, one employs `\makespecialtable[`rows`]`, where "rows" is the number of rows to printout, so as not to extend past a page break.  Multiple invocations of `\makespecialtable` will proceed through the rows, until the table rows are exhausted.

In this MWE, I use `\sixby` four times.  Then I output the table with

```
\makespecialtable[3]
\makespecialtable
```

In this way, rows(1-3)cols(1-3) appear on p.1, rows(1-3)cols(4-6) appear on page 2, row(4)cols(1-3) appear on p.3 and row(4)cols(4-6) appear on page 4.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tabindex}
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{%
  \@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks\stepcounter{tabindex}#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\synctabindex[1]{\setcounter{tabindex}{\value{#1}}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\def\colwidth{1in}
\newcounter{sptstartrow}
\newcounter{sptendrow}
\newcounter{entries}

\newcommand\newspecialtable{%
  \setcounter{sptendrow}{0}%
  \setcounter{entries}{0}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\sixby[6]{%
  \stepcounter{entries}%
  \expandafter\protected@edef\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xa\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\protected@edef\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xb\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\protected@edef\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xc\endcsname{#3}%
  \expandafter\protected@edef\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xd\endcsname{#4}%
  \expandafter\protected@edef\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xe\endcsname{#5}%
  \expandafter\protected@edef\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xf\endcsname{#6}%
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\makespecialtable[1][\theentries]{%
  \setcounter{sptstartrow}{\thesptendrow}%
  \addtocounter{sptendrow}{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\thesptendrow > \theentries}{\setcounter{sptendrow}{\theentries}}{}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xa\endcsname &
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xb\endcsname &
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xc\endcsname & 
      \vphantom{%
        \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xd\endcsname\strut}%
        \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xe\endcsname\strut}%
        \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xf\endcsname\strut}%
      }
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|p{\colwidth}|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xd\endcsname &
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xe\endcsname &
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xf\endcsname &
      \vphantom{%
        \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xa\endcsname\strut}%
        \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xb\endcsname\strut}%
        \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xc\endcsname\strut}%
      }%
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|p{\colwidth}|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\newspecialtable
\sixby
  {Row 1: Title of column 1 maybe a bit longer than column 3}%
  {this is a test of a longer line}%
  {BC}%
  {while this is a test of a particularly extended line spanning a
    number of rows, more than all the others.  And I really mean more than all the others}%
  {xcxcx}%
  {T}
\sixby
  {Row 2: this is a test of a longer line}%
  {Here is some text for this entry}%
  {while this is a test of a particularly extended line spanning a
    number of rows, more than all the others}%
  {F}%
  {T}%
  {column 6 entry maybe a bit longer than column 5}
\sixby
  {Row 3: this is a test of a longer line}%
  {BC}%
  {F}%
  {T}%
  {while this is a test of a particularly extended line spanning a
    number of rows, more than all the others}%
  {column 6 entry maybe a bit longer than column 5}
\sixby
  {Row 4: this is a test of an extended rows}%
  {x}%
  {a word}%
  {column 6 entry maybe a bit longer than column 5}
  {final line}%
  {}%
\centering
\makespecialtable[3]% Print 3 rows of the table (so as not to exceed page boundary)
\makespecialtable
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This would work, except it looks like I would have to manually control the page breaks. I have hundreds of pages of text, so I would rather not have to do that. Is it possible to automate the page breaks?

Comment: @PeterOlson I have an idea, but even if it works, it won't allow an item to be split across pages.  At best, I'll be able to check if adding a row would force a page break, and if so, print out the page before adding the row.  Would that work for you?

Comment: I've been playing with it some. The only that's bothering me is it doesn't fill up the entire page, neither vertically nor horizontally (this is especially jarring on larger page sizes), but I might be able to fix this myself if I tinker with it more. Is there an easy way to make the columns fit to the width of the page and to make rows go all the way to the end of the page?

Comment: @PeterOlson  I presume you found my `\textheight=4in\relax` setting (used for demonstration purposes), which must also be reset to the desired value.

Comment: I figured out that it was caused by putting `>{\raggedright}` and `>{\raggedleft}` in the column definitions. It aligns fine when the columns are justified.

Comment: I imagine the `\ragged...` forms could be used, as long as they was also carried into the `\parbox`es which are used for the `\vphantom`s.  In any event, I'm glad it works for you.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bugging you, but I'm having trouble with using any sort of environment within a `\sixby`, such as `\begin{center}...\end{center}` or `\begin{quote}...\end{quote}`. I don't really understand what's going on, is there some sort of conflict that's causing this problem?

Comment: @PeterOlson Fixed.  In the end, it was simple.  The six `\protected@edef` macros at the beginning of `\sixby` were changed to plain `\def` definitions.  Now, both centering and quotes work, as shown on first page.

Answer (score 1):

The question is tackled here via tabular environment with `0.3\linewidth`, top alignment. Since your output also requires vertical alignment for second headings, thereby a `parbox` with 3cm for height is used.

```
\newcommand*{\heading}[1]{#1\\\hline}
\newcommand*{\body}[1]{\parbox[t][3cm]{0.3\textwidth}{#1}\\}
%------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|p{0.3\linewidth}}\hline  
\heading{Heading 1}
\body{English text taking up 3 lines \\ and More}%
\heading{Heading 2}
\body{Continue as usual.}\hline
\end{tabular}%
%------------------------------------------------                               
\begin{tabular}[t]{|p{0.3\linewidth}}\hline 
\heading{Title 1}
\body{The is the text filling up the second column. The is the text filling up the second column.}%
\heading{Title 2}
\body{Continue as usual.}\hline
\end{tabular}%
%-----------------------------------------------                              
\begin{tabular}[t]{|p{0.3\linewidth}|}\hline
\heading{Primero 1}
\body{This is the text filling the third column. This is the text filling the third column. 
This is the text filling the third column.}%
\heading{Primero 2}
\body{Continue as usual.}\hline
\end{tabular}                               
\end{document}
```

No particular package is used. Here the height of `\parbox` 3cm can be changed. `\textwidth` can be changed to, for example `\linewidth`. Macros -- heading and body -- are designed for user to be free from LaTeX setting and are subject to modify to suit your needs.

[image]

Updated: This one would address the OP's wishlist. The Parallel package is used, inspired by John Kormylo.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parallel}

\newcommand*{\heading}[1]{{\strut #1\strut}}     
\newcommand*{\body}[1]{{\vspace{0pt}\strut #1\strut \par}}
\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}
\ParallelLText{
\begin{tabular}[t]{|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|} \hline
\heading{Heading 1} &
\heading{Heading 2} & 
\heading{Heading 3}  \\ \hline
\body{English text taking up 1 lines  and More} & 
\body{English text taking up 3 lines  and More, English text taking up 3 lines  and More} &
\body{English text taking up 4 lines  and More. English text taking up 4 lines  and More. English text taking up 4 lines  and More} \\ 
\heading{Title 1} &
\heading{Title 2 and more and more and more and more} & 
\heading{Title 3}  \\ \hline
\body{English text taking up 3 lines  and More} & 
\body{Continue as usual.} &
\body{Continue as usual.} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\ParallelRText{
\begin{tabular}[t]{|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|} \hline
\heading{Title 1} &
\heading{Title 2 and more and more and more and more} & 
\heading{Title 3}  \\ \hline
\body{English text taking up 3 lines  and More} & 
\body{Continue as usual.} &
\body{Continue as usual.} \\ 
\heading{Heading 1} &
\heading{Heading 2} & 
\heading{Heading }  \\ \hline
\body{English text taking up 3 lines  and More} & 
\body{Continue as usual.} &
\body{Continue as usual.} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for, for a few reasons: the cell height is fixed, rather than being based on the height of the content, and you didn't adress how to make the right page align with the left page.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why this answer got so many downvotes? Even though it apparently does not address the OPs wishlist in every respect, it is by no means ultra-low quality.

Comment: @Daniel It's because it doesn't touch the difficulty of the question at all. Creating a 3 column table with manually entered height for each row is relatively trivial. The question is really about how to make the columns align vertically *by their content across two pages*.

Comment: Suggested by John Kormylo, using Parallel package does constitute a possible solution. (i.e., columns align vertically ... across two pages.) This is how -- \begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}\ParallelLText{....} \ParallelRText{....}\end{Parallel} where .... is the given code.  Thanks.

Comment: But the Parallel package only allows two columns, not three, and with the page option will only align once per page.

Comment: @Peter Olson -- Would you please check the latest update. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PeterOlson (and others): Yes, I agree. But this may also be caused by some simple misunderstanding or a suboptimal description of the problem – you never know. We usually leave a comment regarding the open issues and just don't *upvote* in such case. 5 downvotes for a (maybe naïve, but true) attempt to help is pretty rude for tex.se standards!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131394/51244). An improvement is to have a table with columns of different widths.
And tables of several double pages, it is interesting to have a reminder of the header of column (ie the first line) in every page.

This solution was proposed here: http://blog.m123.be/pluxml/index.php?article16/howto-ecrire-un-tableaux-sur-plusieurs-double-page-en-latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually, it is better to show a solution in form of [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/13304) as links may become broken with time.