# Parallel Text (Translation) Including the Same/Double/Parallel Heading Numbering

Tags: paracol, reledpar, parallel, parcolumns, parallel-texts

I want to write a bilingual document with paragraph wise parallel translations (two column layout) -- something like this:

[image]

- I also want to have structural elements like picture captions and headings in two versions.
- Ideally the caption and heading numbers are the same for both
  versions/languages.
- I am not looking for a hacky solution.
- I want to use pictures, tables, pgf/tikz and so on in the text.
- I would like to use the koma book class

> - Is that (without hacking) possible?
> - What package do you recommend?

I list some related packages at the end of the post. I am not sure if a minimal example makes sense here. What do you think?

## Related Packages I Found so far

- [parcolumns](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns) (latest update 2004)
- [parrun](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parrun) (latest update 2004)
- [parallel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parallel) (latest update 2003)
- [multicolpar](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicolpar) (latest update 1993)
- [pdfcolparallel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcolparallel) (latest update 2016, fixes bugs in [parallel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parallel))
- [pdfcolparcolumns](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcolparcolumns) (latest update 2016, fixes bugs in [parcolumns](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns))
- [paracol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) (latest update 2018 `-->` I [reported a bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425632) to the author and now **I use this package**. [as of 2018-10-12])
- There is a package family with a lot of history. The main package ends with edmac. Here's the chronological order (oldest first): **edmac**, l**edmac**, el**edmac** and the current [rel**edmac**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledmac) (last updated 2018). For the parallel feature that I am looking for, the family offers a package that ends with **edpar**. The current package is called [rel**edpar**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledpar).

Eventually I found out that there is a [CTAN topic page](https://www.ctan.org/topic/parallel) about this (parallel texts/columns) :).

It seeems that there are two current solutions:

- [paracol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) and
- [reledpar](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledpar) in combination with [reledmac](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledmac)

## Follow-up Questions

- [Getting Started with reledmac/reledpar Package (Parallel Text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308306)

Comment: Here's a question on parallel texts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130907/how-do-i-create-6-parallel-texts-aligned-by-paragraph-with-3-texts-on-each-page  While it shows lines between the `tabular` entries, those can be eliminated from a solution.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes For a whole document?

Comment: I think eledpar is the successor to ledpar and reledpar is the successor to eledpar. Similarly for reledmac etc. I would start by seeing if one of the dedicated packages meets your needs. Start with a standard class. If that does what you need, see if it is compatible with KOMA. You may have to hack something if you really insist on that.

Comment: @cfr Thanks a lot for the hints. I try reledmac/reledpar and post a question if I need help. But my main concern remains - the parallel section numbering. I want the headings in both languages parallel. So every heading number would be double. Any ideas?

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Thanks for the hint - see my comment for cfr. I also updated my research of related packages.