# How to align paragraphs across booklet pages

Tags: formatting, alignment

I’m looking to make a custom Passover Haggadah. How would I make a booklet with paragraphs aligned across pages like below:

[image: haggadah]

So the translations match up

Comment: There are some options listed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308260/parallel-text-translation-including-the-same-double-parallel-heading-numbering, the most useful is probably the [paracol package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol).

Comment: @Marijn This looks like it works for two columns on one page. How can I get this to work across the pages of a booklet?

Comment: You could typeset it as landscape pages with English left and Hebrew right, and then cut all pages in two parts by clipping in LaTeX or external tools like `pdfcrop`, then print it as booklet. Not ideal of course, but it can be automated.